# java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped:

Tags: android, android-layout, exception, android-intent

i got this exception " E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped: "
any idea?

This is the trace i got

> ? E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is already
>   stopped: {pre.com.app/pre.com.app.MainActivity}
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is
>   already stopped: {pre.com.app/pre.com.app.MainActivity} at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4115)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1738)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6615) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
>   2018-12-11 10:45:20.214 11206-11206/? E/ActivityThread:
>   ActivityClientRecord{paused=true, stopped=true, hideForNow=false,
>   startsNotResumed=false, isForward=true, pendingConfigChanges=0,
>   onlyLocalRequest=false, preserveWindow=false, Activity{resumed=false,
>   stopped=true, finished=false, destroyed=false, startedActivity=false,
>   temporaryPause=false, changingConfigurations=false}}

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: the trace i got E/ActivityThread:
ActivityClientRecord{paused=true, stopped=true, hideForNow=false,
  startsNotResumed=false, isForward=true, pendingConfigChanges=0,
  onlyLocalRequest=false, preserveWindow=false, Activity{resumed=false,
  stopped=true, finished=false, destroyed=false, startedActivity=false,
  temporaryPause=false, changingConfigurations=false}}

Comment: Can you give the whole stack trace and what flow makes it crash?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped: {pre.com.app/pre.com.app.MainActivity} at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4115) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1738) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6615)